# Getting subchilds in XML right

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to get to some subchilds in some XML data i need to parse. But I am not getting it(I am new to parsing XML). Hopfully someone can point me in the right direction

Tried a lot of code and searching for answers on google

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xmlParser

xmlText = xmlParser.fromstring('<?xml version="1.0"?><response><params><bins><bin><bin_id>12004</bin_id><bins_above>1</bins_above><xpos>21</xpos><ypos>21</ypos><depth>362</depth></bin></bins></params></response>')

print xmlText.tag



for params in xmlText.iter('params'):
    for bins in params.iter('bins'):
        for bin in bins.iter('bin'):
            for depth_tag in bin.find("depth"):
                print( depth_tag.text )
```

What I want is the depth info or any info within the bin child, but if I get the depth I can get around to the others if needed.

Not sure if I am on the right track or not.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Might be more efficient to simply use an xpath expression instead of all those loops. https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Not sure how I can use xpath for this, do you have an example for xpath used on XML similar to mine or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(
    '<?xml version="1.0"?><response><params><bins><bin><bin_id>12004</bin_id><bins_above>1</bins_above><xpos>21</xpos><ypos>21</ypos><depth>362</depth></bin></bins></params></response>')

depth_lst = [d.text for d in root.findall('.//depth')]
print(depth_lst)
```

output

```
['362']
```